# printing seconds one by one in loop with sleep() function

Tags: printing, ubuntu, sleep, seconds

```
for(j = 1; j < 11; j++)
        {
            printf("%ds ",j);
            sleep(1);
        }
```

i have expected that this code will print "1s 2s 3s ... 10s" where there is 1 second interval between them but instead it prints all the numbers after 10 seconds. how should i fix it? 
i'm working on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stdout` stream is buffered, so if you immediately want your results you need to flush that buffer with `fflush()`:

```
for (j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
    printf("%ds ", j);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a \n to your printf to flush.

```
for(j = 1; j < 11; j++)
        {
            printf("%ds\n",j);
            sleep(1);
        }
```

For more info, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-string).

Comment: Incorrect. Newlines are not required to flush the stdout buffer and more importantly will break the original asker's format.

Comment: It was just a suggestion; I posted the link to a previous question that talks all about fflush() and disabling the buffer. Let's not rehash it all here, let him read the original question.

Comment: Let's not rehash it all here? You suggested something completely irrelevant: newlines. Only one part of your answer was useful, an other question.

Comment: @nightcracker: I might not have formulated it in the best possible way, but what I tried to say was that it didn't print till the end because the buffer wasn't flushed, something that printf automatically does when you put a newline character into your print string.

Comment: although only when printing to a terminal.